# Interpretation of zero-one-inflated beta models in brms

Tags: r, bayesian, zero-inflation, beta-regression

I have 20 participants who have watched 18 clips. Every clip belongs to one category of pleasure (p_cat: negative, neutral, positive) and one category of intensity (i_cat: low, medium, high). I have 2 different clips for each combination of p_cat and i_cat (3 * 3 combinations).

In terms of the response variables, the participants evaluate the clips on two sliders: pleasure and intensity of emotion respectively. The sliders had hidden values, that were continuous in $[0, 1]$.

I am working for the first time with Bayesian statistics and the `brms` R package. After looking into several sources, I concluded that I should use a `zero_one_inflated_beta` family for my model, since I have several zeros and ones. One of my main sources is Matti Vuorre's [How to analyse visual analog (slider) scale data?](https://vuorre.netlify.com/post/2019/02/18/analyze-analog-scale-ratings-with-zero-one-inflated-beta-models/#introduction)

Here are the formulas I used for two models:

```
pleasure ~  p_cat * i_cat + age + experience + gender + (1|item) + (1 |subject)

intensity ~  p_cat * i_cat + age + experience + gender + (1|item) + (1 |subject)
```

I used random effects for participants and items (clips), since every participant evaluates every clip. I have the following questions:

1. In the summary of the fitted model, the lower and upper 95% CI for all  covariates contain $0s$. Does this mean that the covariates do not have an effect, or I need to antilogit before attempting to interpret the results?
2. I understand that I need to antilogit before doing contrasts analysis. For contrasts, I use the following code adapted from [Andrey Anikin's example](https://bayesat.github.io/lund2018/slides/andrey_anikin_slides.pdf) to see if the pleasure response differs between neutral and negative levels of p_cat (`fit$p_catNeu` and `fit$p_catNeg` respectively,  which I've got with `posterior_samples()`, and antilogit):

```
neu_vs_neg = fit$p_catNeu - fit$p_catNeg
> quantile(neu_vs_neg, probs = c(.5, .025, .975)) 
        50%        2.5%       97.5% 
 0.11766086 -0.04730185  0.29740290 
> mean(neu_vs_neg > 0)
[1] 0.92725
```

How can I interpret it? Following Andrey's example (slides 35 and 36), I would say:  *Are neutral clips evaluated with higher pleasure compared to negative clips?  Possibly yes, 11.7% higher, but the evidence is not very strong.* And for the mean of the differences that are greater than zero: *we are 92.7% confident that neutral clips are evaluated higher in pleasure compared to negative clips.* But for me this is confusing; I have weak evidence but high confidence to answer the question positively?

3. How about the Family Specific Parameters estimates *phi, zoi, coi*? How do I deal with them? I understand the estimates I get in the Population-Level Effects summary are the *mu*. Are these enough to show contrasts, or do I need additional regressions for *phi, zoi, coi* in a `bf()` as Matti Vuorre does in his example?